# Change unicode to actual character?

Tags: python, unicode

I have this string `\\u2605` which codes for `★`, and I want to change it so that:

1. It prints either `★` or the "?" command prompt replacement, rather than `\\u2605`
2. I can send the string into functions as `★` not `\\u2605`

How do I change/encode the string?

Comment: I'm maybe being a bit pedantic, but `\u2605` (one slash) is the unicode escape for ★, not `\\u2652`. What you show is a 6 character string of ascii characters. If you send it into a function its still the 6 character string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the bytes to `decode('unicode-escape')`:

```
s = '\\u2605 Amazing \\u2605'

s = bytes(s, 'utf8').decode( 'unicode-escape' )

print(s)
# ★ Amazing ★
```

**note**: not sure if this is a problem in your case, but `decode( 'unicode-escape' )` does not handle un-escaped, non-ascii, so something like `s = '\\u2605 Ama ★ zing \\u2605'` would cause problems. See [issue here](https://bugs.python.org/issue21331). A possible solution in this case is to escape the entire string and then decode:

```
s = s.encode('ascii','backslashreplace').decode( 'unicode-escape' )
```

Answer (score 0):

For all of those who have this issue in Pycharm terminal or run window, change in settings: Editor -> General -> Console -> Default Encoding to UTF-8